# Merge [tag:paperwhite] into [tag:kindle-paperwhite]; make the first a synonym of the second

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retagging

We currently have the tags [paperwhite](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwhite) and [kindle-paperwhite](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle-paperwhite). Both tags are about the same device by Amazon; the summary for [paperwhite](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwhite) even claims

> Kindle Paperwhite, a specific eink device made by Amazon.

I suggest to make [paperwhite](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwhite) a synonym of [kindle-paperwhite](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle-paperwhite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Done.](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/tags/kindle-paperwhite/synonyms)

Comment: Thanks. Upvote? :-)